# Swift execute asynchronous tasks in order

Tags: ios, swift, asynchronous, afnetworking

I have a few asynchronous, network tasks that I need to perform on my app. Let's say I have 3 resources that I need to fetch from a server, call them `A`, `B`, and `C`. Let's say I have to finish fetching resource `A` first before fetching either `B` or `C`. Sometimes, I'd want to fetch `B` first, other times `C` first.

Right now, I just have a long-chained closure like so:

```
func fetchA() {
  AFNetworking.get(completionHandler: {
    self.fetchB()
    self.fetchC()
  })
}
```

This works for now, but the obvious limitation is I've hard-coded the order of execution into the completion handler of `fetchA`. Now, say I want to only `fetchC` after `fetchB` has finished in that completion handler, I'd have to go change my implementation for `fetchB`...

Essentially, I'd like to know if there's some magic way to do something like:

```
let orderedAsync = [fetchA, fetchB, fetchC]
orderedAsync.executeInOrder()
```

where `fetchA`, `fetchB`, and `fetchC` are all async functions, but `fetchB` won't execute until `fetchA` has finished and so on. Thanks!

Comment: Unrelated, but you might consider using Alamofire instead of AFNetworking. It's by the same author, but a Swift solution. But you still need to do something to handle asynchronous tasks, either PromiseKit, some asynchronous `Operation` subclass to wrap the requests, or something similar.

Comment: If you did stay within AFNetworking, I did a little `NSOperation` wrapper for it: https://github.com/robertmryan/AFHTTPSessionOperation

Answer (score 18):

You can use a serial `DispatchQueue` mixed with a `DispatchGroup` which will ensure that only one execution block will run at a time.

```
let serialQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "serialQueue")
let group = DispatchGroup()
group.enter()
serialQueue.async{  //call this whenever you need to add a new work item to your queue
    fetchA{
        //in the completion handler call
        group.leave()
    }
}
serialQueue.async{
    group.wait()
    group.enter()
    fetchB{
        //in the completion handler call
        group.leave()
    }
}
serialQueue.async{
    group.wait()
    group.enter()
    fetchC{
        group.leave()
    }
}
```

Or if you are allowed to use a 3rd party library, use `PromiseKit`, it makes handling and especially chaining async methods way easier than anything `GCD` provides. See the [official GitHub](https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit) page for more info.
You can wrap an async method with a completion handler in a Promise and chain them together like this:

```
Promise.wrap(fetchA(completion:$0)).then{ valueA->Promise<typeOfValueB> in
    return Promise.wrap(fetchB(completion:$0)
}.then{ valueB in

}.catch{ error in
    //handle error
}
```

Also, all errors are propagated through your promises.

Comment: Included a DispatchGroup in the solution, now it works for sure. Also provided PromiseKit as an alternative.

Comment: Promises are the way to go!

Comment: is `group.enter` etc. supposed to be `dispatchGroup.enter`?

Comment: as @dan said the second option (promises) won't work if wrapped operations (fetchA/B/C) are asynchronous themselves. The first one (with GCD groups and 'wait') should work though

Comment: @slava have you actually tried wrapping async functions with completion handlers in Promises? It will work just fine, that's what the `Promise.wrap` function is for...

Comment: @DávidPásztor actually I'm doing that now, but without any luck. The only moment is that `Promise.wrap` is deprecated in the latest `PromiseKit` in favor of `Promise.init(resolver:)` and I'm using that instead. In general I'm wrapping async operations with promises and chaining them with `then` after that. I'd really appreciate any help with that. I can create a repo with my demo code or ask a separate question here on SO if it would be more appropriate.

Comment: @slava sadly I haven't use PromiseKit since the last big rewrite (version 6 if I remember correctly), so not sure what the latest syntax is instead of `wrap`. Creating a separate question with your issue is definitely a good idea though

Comment: Is serialQueue needed in this case? I think concurrent queue would work too, as you are using groups.

Comment: @Sandeep you're right, a concurrent queue would work as well

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why other answers are adding unnecessary code, what you are describing is already the default behavior for a serial queue:

```
let fetchA = { print("a starting"); sleep(1); print("a done")}
let fetchB = { print("b starting"); sleep(1); print("b done")}
let fetchC = { print("c starting"); sleep(1); print("c done")}

let orderedAsync = [fetchA, fetchB, fetchC]
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "fetchQueue")

for task in orderedAsync{
    queue.async(execute: task) //notice "async" here
}

print("all enqueued")
sleep(5)
```

"all enqueued" will print immediately, and each task will wait for the previous one to finish before it starts.

FYI, if you added `attributes: .concurrent` to your `DispatchQueue` initialization, then they wouldn't be guaranteed to execute in order. But even then you can use the `.barrier` flag when you want things to execute in order.

In other words, this would also fulfill your requirements:

```
let queue = DispatchQueue(label: "fetchQueue", attributes: .concurrent)

for task in orderedAsync{
    queue.async(flags: .barrier, execute: task)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use combination of dispatchGroup and dispatchSemaphore to perform the asynchronous code blocks in sequence.

- DispatchGroup will maintain the enter and leave to notify when all the task are completed.
- DispatchSemaphore with value 1 will make sure only one block of task is executed

> Sample
>   code where fetchA, fetchB, fetchC are functions with closure (completion handler)

```
// Create DispatchQueue
private let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue", qos: .background)

//value 1 indicate only one task will be performed at once.
private let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

func sync() -> Void {
    let group = DispatchGroup()

    group.enter()
    self.dispatchQueue.async {
        self.semaphore.wait()
        fetchA() { (modelResult) in
            // success or failure handler

            // semaphore signal to remove wait and execute next task
            self.semaphore.signal()
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.enter()
    self.dispatchQueue.async {
        self.semaphore.wait()
        fetchB() { (modelResult) in
            // success or failure handler

            // semaphore signal to remove wait and execute next task
            self.semaphore.signal()
            group.leave()
        }
    }

    group.enter()
    self.dispatchQueue.async {
        self.semaphore.wait()
        fetchC() { (modelResult) in
            // success or failure handler

            // semaphore signal to remove wait and execute next task
            self.semaphore.signal()
            group.leave()
        }
    }        

    group.notify(queue: .main) {

        // Perform any task once all the intermediate tasks (fetchA(), fetchB(), fetchC()) are completed. 
        // This block of code will be called once all the enter and leave statement counts are matched.

    }
}
```