# Several tasks inside a DispatchGroup. Will they run in order?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

In the following code, is it safe to append to an array? Is the order guaranteed to be maintained?

```
let processedData: [SomeType] = []
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
for _ in 0..<N {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    startSomeAsyncTaskXYZ { (data, error) in
        // handle error and process data
        // add processed data to an array
        processedData.append(..)
        dispatchGroup.leave()
    }
}
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    // update UI
}
```

Comment: No order will be

Comment: to order, your func in cycle must be sync, but you always can sort your array data as you wish

Comment: Chris' answer is working if you just need the output to be in the right order. If you need those tasks to *begin* and *finish* sequentially, then you might take a look at [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue).

Comment: Came across [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45682663/11588848), that only uses the DispatchQueue and DispatchGroup. Haven't tried it. Thanks for mentioning OperationQueue (never heard of it)

Comment: If `startSomeAsyncTaskXYZ` represents some (relatively) long-running process which can be performed independently and in parallel (e.g. a network request), then I wouldn't recommend an approach which makes them sequential - you're just giving away performance. The code in your original question only needs minor modification to achieve good performance, correctly ordered storage and a single final completion when all tasks have completed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To stick with `DispatchGroup` while preserving the desired asynchronous nature and the expected ordering, make your array an array of optionals and populate it in whatever order the tasks complete:

```
var processedData: [SomeType?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: N)
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
for idx in 0..<N {
    dispatchGroup.enter()
    startSomeAsyncTaskXYZ { (data, error) in
        // Ensure we always .leave() after we're done
        // handling the completion of the task
        defer { dispatchGroup.leave() }

        guard let data = data,
              error == nil else {
            // TODO: Actual error handling
            return
        }

        // This needs to be .sync now (not .async) to ensure
        // the deferred dispatchGroup.leave() is not called
        // until *after* we've updated the array
        DispatchQueue.main.sync {
            processedData[idx] = SomeType(data: data)
        }
    }
}
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
    // update UI
}
```

Comment: This is broken. There's a race condition on `processedData`.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Would you mind offering a solution?

Comment: @Alexander please elaborate as I can't see it. `DispatchQueue.main` is a serial queue, so assignments into `processedData` can't overlap. The closure in `dispatchGroup.notify` won't run until the last `dispatchGroup.leave()` so there's no opportunity to attempt to read from `processedData` until it's fully populated.

Comment: @Chris Ah, I didn't notice that this was using a serial queue. My bad!

Comment: @Alexander - no problem, thanks for responding. @exp - I've updated the answer slightly to include somewhere for your error handling while also ensuring `dispatchGroup.leave()` is *always* called, regardless of the outcome of the async task.

Answer (score 3):

`DispatchGroup` has no relevance to execution order. It's merely a way of tracking completion of groups of tasks.

Whether the group's constituent tasks run `async` or `sync`, and in what order, is entirely dependant on how you use `DispatchQueue`s.

Comment: ok, thanks for pointing out the main difference (upvote will count once I have the points for that)

Comment: if I understand it right tasks assigned in the dispatch group can run in any order say task 3 can complete before task 1 is that understanding correct?

Comment: @NSDumb Yeah, DispatchGroup doesn't know or care about the ordering of execution. It just counts the number of `enter`s compared to `leaves`, and signals once all started tasks finish.

Comment: got it, so basically it can pick up any task in random order and start executing it, and its just that we have to match the enter and leave order. Whenever I saw any demo it feels like the dispatch group executes the task in order in which we add them so I assumed it picks up the task in that order

Comment: Are you mixing up queues and groups? I repeat: queues don’t know or care about execution order. They have nothing to do with the execution of dispatch work items. The order of their execution start/finish depends in the order you put them on a queue (they start in FIFO order) and whether the queue is serial (each work item finishes before the next starts) or concurrent (multi work items can start, work concurrently and finish before other ones start)

Answer (score 1):

Just went through this with my app. I have some async tasks that need to be done in order. The best way to accomplish that is through `dispatchGroup()` and `semaphore()`.

The basic idea is that `dispatchGroup` fetches data in no particular order, but `semaphore` goes in a specific order if you need it to.

Here is a good video that demonstrates it: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6rJN_ECd1XM&ab_channel=LetsBuildThatApp

Some sample code would look like this:

```
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue.global(qos: .userInitiated)
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
let semaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

override func viewDidLoad() {
dispatchQueue.async {
        
        // --------------
        // Family members
        // --------------
        
        // Get members and household information first (esp. payday time and time zone), then everything else
        self.dispatchGroup.enter()
        MPUser.loadFamilyMembers {
            
            print("We got us some fambly members!")
            
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            self.semaphore.signal()
        }
        
        // ^^^ Wait for above code to finish ('signal') before moving on (in other words, get users first)
        self.semaphore.wait()

        // --------------
        // Household info
        // --------------

        self.dispatchGroup.enter()
        FamilyData.observeHouseholdInformation {
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
            self.semaphore.signal()
        }

        // ^^^ Wait for above code to finish ('signal') before moving on (in other words, get users first, then household info)
        self.semaphore.wait()

        // ---------------
        // Everything else
        // ---------------

        self.dispatchGroup.enter()
        Setup.observeProgress {
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        
        self.dispatchGroup.enter()
        OutsideIncome.observeUserOutsideIncomeBudget {
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        
        self.dispatchGroup.enter()
        MPUser.observeCurrentEarnings {
            self.dispatchGroup.leave()
        }
        
        self.dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            
            let end = Date()
            print("\nAll functions completed in \(end.timeIntervalSince(self.start!).rounded(toPlaces: 2)) seconds!\n")
            self.sendUserToCorrectPage()
        }
    }
}
```